# Update a GitHub repository without cloning

Tags: github, github-for-windows

Here's the situation, we are currently working on a project and lately we decided to upload it on GitHub. Now I made my changes and I want to push the changes onto the repository.

As far as I read, in order to make changes you need to clone the repository but that will download all files from the repository and I already have all of the source files.

I'm using GitHub desktop and I can't find any option to clone without downloading and update or create branches from my existing files. Creating a local one is an option but it needs to be uploaded as a separate repository instead of linking it to a current one.

Is there any way to push updates, create branches to the repository from my local project to an existing repository?

Comment: You work with a cloned version, because it not only contains the actual versioned files, but also metadata about changes. If you have a working copy, which is already different from the “main” version, you need to clone the repo into one directory, copy your modified files into that directory, then check in. You **definitely** should have an hour or so of a talk in your team, on *why* you are using git and *how* to use it (technically) and *how you* (your team) is going to use it (when using branches, etc)

Comment: I think that won't work, as remote repository and your local repository will not remain in Sync without cloning and that is not recommended at all.

Answer (score 2):

Your local project should already be a git repo, if you uploaded it to GitHub.

But in case it is not, switch to command-line, and do inside the root folder of your project (which should shows the same files as your remote repo):

```
git init .
git remote add origin https://github.com/<user>/<project>
git fetch
```

The fetch part will download the repo but leave your files alone.
(But do a backup still, just to be safe)

```
git branch master origin/master
git reset master
```

From there, your GitHub Desktop should show you any diff between your files and what was fetched from the repo.