# Stop .git/index from changing its permissions

Tags: bash, git, ubuntu, ansible, system-administration

How can I prevent `.git/index` from constantly changing its permissions and ownership?

I run `ls -al .git/index` and see that the file is owned by root.
I change the permissions with `sudo chown -R $USER:USER` and `sudo chmod -R 775 .git`
I even tried deleting the lock file with `rm -rf .git/index.lock`

The permissions update but then a few minutes later they change back to being owned by root and 740 which breaks the git commands I'm attempting.

I set the global git config via Ansible so I'm wondering if that messed something up? Is there a global file I need to modify?

Comment: There's a git process that you are (or someone else is) running as root.

Comment: Is it always changed within a few minutes? When it takes 0-30 minutes, check for puppet running. Did you look at `sudo crontab -l` ? What will happen when you perform `mv .git .git_org` ? Can you run `sudo chown -R $USER:USER; git status` ?

Comment: Always a few minutes. How do I check for puppet? No output from crontab -l. What does that git mv do? That sudo chown seems very dangerous?

Comment: How do I find the git process running as root? I tried `ps ax | grep git` and I see one entry but I'm not sure if that's it or not.

Comment: Try using `ps aux`, which will show you the user as well.

Comment: Note that on some Unix-like systems, you need `ps -ef` rather than `ps -aux` or `ps aux`. You mentioned Ubuntu, so there's no need to worry about this here; I put this in for anyone else who comes across this on some other Unix-like OS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When Git writes the index, the way it does so is to create a new file called `.git/index.lock` (with `O_EXCL`), adjusts its permissions according to `core.sharedRepository`, and then rename it over top.  Git does not offer a way to rewrite the file in place.

If this file is being created such that it's being owned by root, then root is creating the file because it's updating the index.  That probably means that some process owned by root is modifying the working tree.

If that wasn't your intention, then the best thing to do is find that process and stop it from modifying the working tree.  It's not a good idea for multiple users to modify the same working tree, and if your process owned by root is reading files out of the working tree and it's shared with another user, that could lead to a security vulnerability.

If you're certain what you're doing is safe and you want to modify the permissions with which files in the `.git` directory are created, you can use `core.sharedRepository` to set them.  For example, you could use the value `0664`.  Note that Git will handle the executable bit automatically, and the index should not be marked executable.

If you want to always use the same group for your repository, you can set the setgid bit on all the directories in the repository and then set their group to the appropriate value.  Assuming you also set `core.sharedRepository` to a value that makes things group writable, you can then modify the repository with any user in that group, and things should work.  Note that this may still have security implications if one or more of those users are untrusted or have lower privileges, so you should be careful.

Comment: How can I figure out the process owned by root? I definitely do not want root running this.

Comment: Look at the file modification time and try to guess what processes are running then.  Or, run a background process to dump the output of `ps aux` plus a timestamp every ten seconds and then look at the output around the time the file is next updated.

Comment: The PID kept changing so I couldn't kill it. Ultimately I removed and reinitialized the git repo using this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52658581/update-a-github-repository-without-cloning

Comment: And that worked the first time and then broke the second. Is there any way to master reset git config on a system?

Comment: Sorry final comment. It may be the script I'm running as it's using both sudo and a regular user. I've just setup a chown in the script for now. Thanks for all your help.